# i have two text box first text box value 1 means second text box value can't exceed 5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

i have **two text box** first text box value *1 means* second text box value can't *exceed 5* like that...1st text box value *2 means* 2nd text box value can,t *exceed 10*. Not a character count

Please advise me

Comment: What??? Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: can you show your code that you hav tried so far??

Comment: no i did't write any code.but i  am searching the code but given example like only character count

Comment: refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/ETYgD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 function result(){
      if( $("#f2").val() > $("#f1").val()*5 ) $("#f2").val($("#f1").val()*5);
    }

    $("#f1").keyup(result).change(result);
    $("#f2").keyup(result).change(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="number" id="f1" value=1/>
    <input type="number" id="f2" value=2/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only javascript !

```js
 function result(){
      if( f2.value > f1.value*5 )
          f2.value = f1.value*5;
    }
```

```html
<form>    
    <input type="number" id=f1 onchange="result()" onkeyup="result()"/>
    <input type="number" id=f2 onchange="result()" onkeyup="result()"/>
</form>
```